# saving a binary file to ram in c#

Tags: c#

i am developing a flash tool for a mobile which sends a loader to it for further 
communications.currently i receive the loader file through web request from a URL
and stores it in disk .below is the code i use

```
private void submitData()
    {
        try
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string cpuid = comboBox1.Text;
            string postdata = "cpuid=" + cpuid;
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("Http://127.0.0.1/fetch.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string path = sr.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(path);

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            WebRequest request1 = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/"+path);
            WebResponse response2 = request1.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response2.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"e:\loader.mbn"))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        DateTime nowTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        if ((nowTime - startTime).TotalMinutes > 1)
                        {
                            throw new ApplicationException(
                                "Download timed out");

                        }

                        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("COMPLETDED");
                }
            }

            sr.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERR :" + ex.Message);
        }
```

my question is there a way to store the file directly to the ram
and then use it from there
so far i tried to use Memory stream with no results.

Comment: MemoryStream works just fine. A simple `responseStream.CopyTo(myMemoryStream)` is enough to copy the input to the memory stream. In fact, you could use the *same* call to save to a file stream. What did you try? What was the problem?

Comment: yes saving works fine but i was unable to send the file to the main program,as it needed loader path and path can only be a string ,either i have to use some other input methods which accepts streams as input or have to discard this idea

Comment: It's impossible to help if you don't actually post the code and explain what's wrong. What does `unable to send` mean? If the data is in the MemoryStream already, why are you asking about `store to RAM` ? Did you forget to reset the stream's position to 0 perhaps?

Comment: Like Moss said: `Memory(Stream) IS ram!`

Comment: This sounds to me like the OP is trying to implement some kind of IPC between 2 applications. If that's the case looking into the [`MemoryMappedFile` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) might be worth a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with MemoryStream. You have to remember to reset the stream's position to the beginning if you want to use the data though.

```
//If the size is known, use it to avoid reallocations
use(var memStream=new MemoryStream(response.ContentLength))
use(var responseStream=response.GetResponseStream())
{
    //Avoid blocking while waiting for the copy with CopyToAsync instead of CopyTo
    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
    //Reset the position
    memStream.Position = 0;
    //Use the memory stream
    ...
}
```

Comment: `private void loadkernel(object sender,EventArgs e){

{
           using (Memorystream strm = new Memorystream(loader))
     {
      stream.Position = 0;
   var sr = new Streamreader(strm);
   srloader = sr.ReadToeND();
     }
    
 File.ReadAllBytes(srloader);

}`

Comment: And where do you *wrtite* to the stream? Don't post code here anyway, update the question. It's very hard to read code in the comments. MemoryStream isnt' broken anwyay

Comment: What path? What code? Which line? What is the full exception? MemoryStream has nothing to do with *paths*. BTW why are you using `File.ReadAllBytes` ? That's for reading files. The stream already contains the data. `srloader` probably is emtpy though, since it's a string generated from the contents of the *empty* MemoryStream

Comment: Update the question, don't post broken images! Besides, the code in the comment could never work. You are using the contents of an *empty* stream as if they were a paht to a *disk* file. That `srLoader` or `strStream` are just empty strings

Comment: Memorystream(loader) is what i used to save the loader in first place,how could it be empty

Comment: Worse, unless `test.txt` contains the *path* of another file. That still has nothing to do with MemoryStream or the question you posted here

Comment: Instead of posting tests, try what I wrote *first*. MemoryStream isn't broken. People would have noticed in the last 15 years if it was